# Exploring and finding patterns/similarity in Data with Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, design-patterns, similarity

as I was learning Python,was working on one of the dataset like this:

```
**Col1**                                 **Col2**      **Col3**        
dog                                        Z             st02          
dog,cat                                    Z             st02          
dog,bat,cat                                Z             st02          
bat,cat,elephant                           Y             st02          
dog,bat,cat,elephant                       Y             st02          
tiger                                      Z             st01          
pigeon                                     Z             st01          
pigeon,parrot                              Z             st01          
dove,parrot                                Z             st01          
pigeon,parrot                              Z             st01          
pigeon,parrot,dove                         Z             st01          
lion,leopard,cheetah                       Z             st01          
tiger,lion,leopard,cheetah                 Z             st01          
dog,tiger,cheetah                          Y             st01          
dog,tiger,leopard,cheetah                  Y             st01          
eagle,jaguar,Kangaroo,zebra                Z             st02          
cheetah,eagle,jaguar,Kangaroo,zebra        Z             st02
```

The expected output is:

```
**Col1**                                 **Col2**       **Col3**      
dog,bat,cat                                Z              st02          
dog,bat,cat,elephant                       Y              st02          
tiger,lion,leopard,cheetah                 Z              st01          
dog,tiger,leopard,cheetah                  Y              st01          
cheetah,eagle,jaguar,Kangaroo,zebra        Z              st02          
pigeon,parrot,dove                         Z              st01
```

In order to extract the above rows as output, I tried tracing the patterns and using the below logic:

```
data = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
data['Col4'] = data['Col1'].str.count(',')
v1 = []
v2 = []
v1.append(0)
v2.append(0)
for i in range(0,data.shape[0]-1):
    x = data['Col2'][i]
    y = data['Col2'][i+1]
    t1 = data['Col3'][i]
    t2 = data['Col3'][i+1]
    g1 = (x == y) & (t1==t2)
    d1 = data['Col1'][i]
    d2 = data['Col1'][i+1]
    c1 = data['Col4'][i]
    c2 = data['Col4'][i+1]
    flag = 0
    if(all(x in d2 for x in d1)):
      flag = 1
    g2 = (flag == 1)&(c2>c1)
    v1.append(g1)
    v2.append(g2)
    data['new_cond1'] = v1   
    data['new_cond2'] = v2   
    data['Final_flag'] = (data['new_cond1']==True)&(data['new_cond2']==True) 
    data_output = data[data['Final_flag']==True]
```

But I didn't end up getting the expected output, rather few additional rows are also present in output. Could someone please help me extracting the rows mentioned in expected output.

---

From the dataset, I am trying to extract 1) Rows which has maximum number of animals separated by commas (or consider birds wherever pigeon/parrot/dove is mentioned). 2) Need not be the case that there should be only one maximum number of animals per Col2 or Col3, there might be even more than one Example as in case of row no. 1 and row no. 5 with same value in Col 2 and Col 3. This is because category of animals is different in row no.1 and row no. 5. Hope it's clear.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what exactly the logic here?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to extract?

Comment: From the dataset, I am trying to extract 1) Rows which has maximum number of animals separated by commas (or consider birds wherever pigeon/parrot/dove is mentioned). 2) Need not be the case that there should be only one maximum number of animals per Col2 or Col3, there might be even more than one `Example` as in case of row no. 1 and row no. 5 with `same value in Col 2 and Col 3`. This is because `category of animals is different in row no.1 and row no. 5`. Hope it's clear.

Comment: `all(x in d2 for x in d1)` - what is that supposed to do?

Comment: The column names in the example DataFrame do not match the labels/names in your code

Comment: @wwii, The column names are the fine now, just removed the underscore in between. all(x in d2 for x in d1) to check for subset

Comment: While this doesn't match your desired output, I would think this would be interesting... `df_reduce = df.copy()
df_reduce = df_reduce.groupby(['**Col2**','**Col3**'])['**Col1**'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
for index, row in df_reduce.iterrows():
    animals = row['**Col1**'].split(',')
    animals = set(animals)
    row['**Col1**'] = str(animals)[1:-1]
print(df_reduce)`

Answer (score 0):

My comment is not formatted well so I'll post an answer to make it more readable.  I know it's not your desired output but it's de-duplicating the rows.

```
#assuming your data is currently in a frame called df...
df_reduce = df.copy()
df_reduce = df_reduce.groupby(['**Col2**','**Col3**'])['**Col1**'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
for index, row in df_reduce.iterrows():
    animals = row['**Col1**'].split(',')
    animals = set(animals)
    row['**Col1**'] = str(animals)[1:-1]
print(df_reduce)
```

Output:

```
  **Col2** **Col3**                                           **Col1**
0        Y     st01               'tiger', 'leopard', 'cheetah', 'dog'
1        Y     st02                    'bat', 'cat', 'elephant', 'dog'
2        Z     st01  'parrot', 'pigeon', 'tiger', 'lion', 'leopard'...
3        Z     st02  'zebra', 'Kangaroo', 'dog', 'eagle', 'cheetah'...
```

Comment: Yes it's deduplicating @MDR, thanks, any clue on generating the desired output?

Comment: sorry, I don't see the logic.  Re-read your post on the logic several times.  It's not clicking with me.  I would perhaps recommend you think about adding columns to the data (re-construct it) that then allows the correct grouping based on logic that is 'inside' the frame (e.g., when col5 > 4, or re.match this or that from row-1 or something like that).  Not sure, maybe it helps.  Good luck!